# Laravel - Validator double - ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Tags: php, laravel, validation, laravel-5.1

Hi have more than 1 forms for a payment procedure

**Here my payment steps**

Step 1 - Form input datas;
Step 2 - Valide data of `Step 1`;
Step 3 - Form input other datas;
Step 4 - Valide data of `Step 2`;

In the second validation, if  validator fail I return...

```
return redirect()->back()->withErrors($validator)->withInput();
```

The problem is that, if the second validation fail, it give me this error int he browser

> ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

I think is due because it redirect()->back() to previous `Step 1` and so to the previous validator... and going in to loop.

Now I'have solved returning a **View**

```
return View('staff.cedola', $data)->withErrors($validator);
```

Is this the right way?

Comment: Why are step 1 and step 2 on the same routes? Prefer splitting them... It will cause less issues. You can have something like `myroute/step/1` and then `myroute/step/2`... Also, please share some code in your controller and view so we can help you more...

Answer (score 0):

inside your middleware or construct() method, you need to check the URL is it the page or not. If it is the current page, you need to skip the redirect.

Below is the example, I hope you get the idea.

```
//if under verificated page no need check to avoid keep redirect
if (!request()->is('member/verified-profile'))
{
    //check Member Porfile Verification
    $this->beforeFilter('@checkUserProfileVerification');
    if (!request()->is('member/verified-mobile'))
    {
        //check Member Mobile Verification
        $this->beforeFilter('@checkUserMobileVerification');
    }
}
```